# Is it possible to access AES key of Self-encrypting drives (SEDs) in userspace?

Tags: linux-kernel, encryption, ioctl

In AES Hardware Encryption, is it possible to send or access AES key to and from hardware to userspace/software?

Is there an available **IOCTL** for this?

Comment: What hardware?  What OS?  What encryption?  The answer is probably "no" regardless.

Comment: Depending on the purpose of the AES hardware encryption module, you may or may not be able to manage keys yourself. If it is an accelerator, then you should use it as a functional unit. If it is a self-contained encryption black box, then most likely it will generate, hold and never show the keys.

Comment: My hardware is a storage device, ATA, using AES256 encryption. I am really curious if its possible that I can query AES key from AES module via some IOCTL commands, ATA security commands maybe. Very much appreciated all your replies. Please advise. Thanks again.